# issue with copy_from_user in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm trying to use this function to copy a buffer from the user to one in kernel.
both buffers were allocated. I'm using `while` in case not all the bytes were copied on the first try. but for some reason, nothing is copied and the program is stuck in the while loop.
what can be the reasons for that?

```
void my_copy_from_user(const char* source_buff, char* dest_buff, int size_to_copy){
    int not_copied = size_to_copy
    int left = size_to_copy;

    while( not_copied ){
        not_copied = copy_from_user(dest_buff, source_buff, left);
        dest_buff += (left - not_copied);
        source_buff += (left - not_copied);
        left = not_copied;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it is legitimately failing for reasons that you cannot recover from.

Please look at: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/lib/usercopy_32.c#L681

```
unsigned long _copy_from_user(void *to, const void __user *from, unsigned n)
{
    if (access_ok(VERIFY_READ, from, n))
        n = __copy_from_user(to, from, n);
    else
        memset(to, 0, n);
    return n;
}
```

This is the underlying implementation for `copy_from_user` for Linux on x86 processors. It first checks `access_ok`. If access is not allowed, it will fail and return with `n` (the number of bytes you requested to copy) immediately. This would cause an infinite loop.

Two points:

- I do not think you should invoke `copy_from_user` in a loop like that. If it fails to copy in kernel mode, there is a *reason* why. This is a different beast from `read()` functions when reading from sockets, etc, where you are encouraged to read() in a loop.
- Are you **sure** that you are passing in the correct `dest_buff` to `copy_from_user`?

Tips:

- Printk all the values and see what's happening. Is `left` being changed or not? It is likely not.

Comment: The information in the link looks useful, but please paste the relevant code here in case the link is broken in the future, and so your answer is more complete.